# Baire 2 and the class of all pointwise limits of sequences of continuous a.e. functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, cantor-set

Let $\Phi_1$ be the family of all pointwise limits of sequences of continuous a.e. functions.

Since there is a continuous a.e. function which is not Baire 1. So, there is a function in $\Phi_1$ but it is not Baire 2. Moreover, there is Baire 1 which is not continuous a.e. It implies that there is a Baire 2 function which is not in $\Phi_1$.

My question:

1. What is a function in Baire 2 but not in $\Phi_1$?
2. What is a function in $\Phi_1$ but not in Baire 2?

For the second question, I think that we have to define the function on set such that the set has positive measure, for example "fat cantor set".